# Universal app popover in iPad version

Tags: ipad, popover

I am converting an iphone app to the iPad version and I am trying to use a popover in a view in the iPad version.
I am getting an apple mach-o linker id error which disappears when the popover view files are deleted from the project.
Is there any build settings changed/frameworks added when using popovers?

Comment: "when the popover view files are deleted from the project" you getting error when files are deleted?

Comment: No errors when popover view files deleted

Answer (score 0):

if you want to compile application for both devices you can put

```
__asm__(".weak_reference _OBJC_CLASS_$_UIPopoverController");
__asm__(".weak_reference _OBJC_CLASS_$_UIPopoverControllerDelegate");
```

into your Prefix.pch. It will remove errors, but you still won't be able to access those Objects - you will have to add `if`'s to check if you running on iPhone or iPad and present information differently.

something like:

```
static BOOL isDeviceIPad(){
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 30200
    if ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad ) {
        return YES;
    }
#endif
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean using UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM macro? if so do you know of any examples the apple Top Paid app example did not answer my question

Comment: Sorry neither of these solutions worked I am getting an "ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 error" what ever I do

Comment: its not use that or that - you have to use both. put `__asm__` part to your pch file and it will help you avoid compiler warnings but not code crashes. To avoid code crashes you have to check at run time if its running iPhone or iPad and change your workflow accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions this has been Solved by adding the new files to the build phases Target>build phases>Compile sources
And target>build phases>Copy bundle resources